# how to round down numbers of a vector in Julia

Tags: julia

I generated a vector with values form the Chi-squared distribution:

```
using Plots, Distributions, Random
c = rand(Chisq(11), 3)
3-element Vector{Float64}:

 5.160148845738397
 6.715592059742631
13.186986070816523
```

How to round-down or floor the values of this vector to get:

```
 5
 6
13
```

Comment: Try looking for truncating. Rounding down generally refers to decimal values with a point value of < 0.5. Truncating just chops off the second half of the number keeping everything before the dot.

Comment: What sort of behaviour do you want for negative numbers? `floor(Int, -2.7)` is `-3`, while `trunc` yields `-2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`floor.(Int, c)` (or `floor.(c)` if you want `Float64` results.